# How can I upload my webapp to Amplify from Gitlab without using a .zip file

Tags: aws-amplify

I am new to HTML/CSS and I'm trying to use Amplify to host my static site.  I can easily use the "manual deploy" option and upload a .zip file.

What is the preferred method of using Gitlab with Amplify so that changes can be easily made?

My goal is to have everything in a repository that's not zipped so I can make constant changes.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to set up hosting for your website using the `Hosting with Amplify Console` option, which provides a git-based workflow for building, deploying, and hosting your website direct from source control.

You can trigger this workflow by running `amplify add hosting` in your project directory. Next, select the `Hosting with Amplify Console` option. Then, select the `Continuous deployment` option. This will open a browser window and take you to your amplify-project homepage. Here, click on the Frontend Environments tab, select your repository provider, and click "Connect branch". You will have to follow the steps to authorize Amplify to access your repository. Once your  provider is authorized, you should see a dropdown menu with a list of your repositories. Select the appropriate repository and branch and click "Next".

Next, confirm your build settings. Assuming your website resides at the root of your project directory, your build settings should likely look something like the following:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: []
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

Again, click "Next". On the next screen, choose "Save and Deploy". Assuming all things were configured correctly, Amplify should now clone your repository and deploy it. You can now confirm that the process has executed properly by following the link provided by the CLI. Hereafter, every and anytime you push changes to your website to gitlab, Amplify will re-deploy your website automatically.

See [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/hosting#using-aws-amplify-console) for further info!